# How to print memory usage of an algorithm in Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, memory-management

I wrote two algorithms in Pyspark and I need to compare memory usages of these two algorithm and report the best one. is there any way to calculate the memory or RAM usage of any chunk of code in Pyspark?

I search in the spark documentation but I did not find any way and I also somehow a new user of pyspark.

Comment: If you try to execute the application using `spark-submit` then Spark Master Web UI will provide detailed resource utilization, execution plan, etc information. Also, here are some third-party tools mentioned, have a look for benchmarking related: https://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html **AND** https://spark.apache.org/developer-tools.html

Comment: thanks. I checked these pages but actually there was no solution for my issue, is there a simple way to just see the ram usage of a block of codes?

Comment: I think simplest would be, to run PySpark script in cluster local mode and observe the resource utilization using `top` command!

Comment: thanks. it helped. but I guess using python library works good enough for my issue.

Comment: @CodeByAM Can you share what python library you are talking about ?

Comment: Hello @abdennacer-lachiheb. First, I needed a simple way not an accurate or complex one. So I just wanted to know how much memory a block of code uses. There are 3 main ways to do that in python:  I used tracemalloc library because it is the simplest way but the other methods are: Psutil and memory profiler.